# JSP support not configured. Maven-приложение

Tags: java, spring, jsp, maven

Хочу сделать приложение для аутентификации на сайте через Spring Security.
Создал Maven-проект, в директорию webapp загрузил jsp-файл. Настроил `pom.xml`. Попытался запустить: порт открылся, но вместо своей странички я увидел сообщение:

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /secure-exam/index.jsp. Reason:

JSP support not configured
```

Как мне настроить этот JSP?

Comment: Какой редактор вы используете ?

Comment: @Saidolim Eclipse

Comment: `javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api` и `jsp-api` добавили в pom?

Comment: @Saidolim, я в этом новичок. Откуда-то скопировал. [Вот содержимое pom](http://pastebin.com/PFW8hAay)

Comment: нужен ваш код или логи что бы понять полностью ваш вопрос

Comment: @Saidolim [Логи](http://pastebin.com/9XhTHfYk). Я не понимаю, почему оно не хочет запускаться. Сделал как вы сказали. Как проверить, скачался ли файл? Новичку в спринге и вообще в большом программировании как то сложновато.

Comment: @Saidolim а кода вообще нет. я просто создал проект, добавил в pom файл все, закинул в папку файл .jsp и попытался запустить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в `pom` следуюшее

```
<javax.servlet.jsp>2.2.1-b03</javax.servlet.jsp>
<jstl-api>1.2.1</jstl-api>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>${javax.servlet.jsp}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
    <version>${jstl-api}</version>
</dependency>
```

если используете `apache tiles` нужно еще

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
    <version>${org.apache.tiles.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>${org.apache.tiles.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
    <version>${org.apache.tiles.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Не помогло почему-то.

Comment: @mrblamber проверьте там вы скачали файл `org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet` из maven? если нет проблема где то там

Comment: @mrblamber задача решилась ? или что то еще добавили?